# What is the technique of solving the following? Area of circle is increasing 3 times as fast as its radius in centimeters. What is the radius?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, related-rates

I have a general idea that it is solved by using derivatives, but I am having a hard time converting text into equations?

Problem: Area of expanding circle is increasing 3 times as fast as its radius in centimeters. What is the radius?

Comment: Do you know calculus and derivatives and the area of a circle?

Comment: The radius is measured in centimeters, but you haven't told us what units are used to measure the area.

Comment: Problem asks for the radius in terms of Pi.

Comment: Yes Daniel, I am just having a hard time converting words into formulas. I can solve regular problems but having hard time with word problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Area of expanding circle is increasing 3 times as fast as its radius" can be written mathematically as $$\frac{dA}{dt}=3\frac{dr}{dt}$$ because the derivative of the area is the rate at which the area changes and likewise for the radius. You also know that the area of a circle is $$A=\pi r^2.$$ Now take the derivative of the area formula so that you have a second formula for $\frac{dA}{dt}$. Can you see how to solve for the radius from here?

Comment: So the derivative of area equal 3 times the derivative of radius?

Comment: Yes, that's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: So derivative of area equal to $A=\pi 2r$, so $\pi 2r = 3 \frac {dr}{dr}$? So to solve for radius I have to divide both sides by $2\pi$? How to get rid of $\frac {dr}{dr}$ part then?

Comment: You have the right idea, but recheck your derivative of the area. You should get $$\frac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r \frac{dr}{dt}$$ by the chain rule because you are differentiating implicitly.

Comment: Wow thank you for helping me to figure this out by guiding. At the end answer is $r=\frac{3}{2\pi}$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{d}{dr}A(r) = 3$ where $A(r) = \text{area of a circle with radius $r$}$.